# Android e requisição HTTP campo X-auth-token

Tags: android, codeigniter, http, http-headers

Eu estou tentando enviar um token, através de uma aplicação Android no campo 'X-auth-token' do header. Esta requisição é enviada para um servidor PHP, no qual uso CodeIgniter.

Android

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL_PATH);
    httpPost.setHeader("X-auth-token", token);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nome", this.nome_value));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
    httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
          //...
        }
```

Server

```
...
$res = $CI->input->request_headers()['X-auth-token'];
...
```

**Problema:** $res não está setado, como se o campo 'X-auth-token' não existisse.

*1 - Como posso enviar o campo do header 'X-auth-token' no Android?*

*2 - Eu estou usando o campo 'X-auth-token' porque eu li que é mais seguro do que um campo de post normal, para enviar dados confidencias.*

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de você usar uma biblioteca? Eu passo um token mas não uso o `HttpClient`. Se existir eu posso te mostrar como faço no meu caso

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde.
Cara, encontrei o mesmo problema com o Authorization.
Fiz uma regra pra reescrevê-lo  no .htaccess conforme segue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Creio que, se tu simplesmente alterar `HTTP:Authorization` e `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1`, deverá funcionar.